# .skp to unity not picking up the models

Tags: unity-game-engine, sketchup

Hi i'm trying to export the .skp file from sketchup and uploading into unity but its not picking up the right format.

My unity version: 2021.3 and on silicon m1

[image]

I've tried both 2021 and 2020 versions but do not work. Any idea?

[image]

I also recently tried importing as a new asset but the .skp somehow is not picked up.. any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Did you read the Unity documentation that tells you how to do it? It doesn’t look like you followed it

Comment: I did. and its confirmed a bug. It works on unity version 2020 but not on 2021.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed a macos bug for 2021.3

For time being, temporary workaround is to import on 2020 and then copy the scene over.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/sketchup-skp-to-unity-2021-3-not-picking-up-asset-works-in-2020.1334432/#post-8434253